# How can I pick up new changes after I repo sync?

Tags: git, repository

I create my repository using repo init and then repo sync.
Then I create my dev branch locally using 'git checkout -b my_dev'.

I made commits to my my_dev branch.
Then I need to pick up new changes committed by others. I switched to my branch with a remote tracking branch. And do a 'repo sync'

My question is how can I go back to my my_dev branch to continue my work. I need those new changes I picked up after I did the repo sync?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pick up remote changes in git, you need can run `git fetch`, which updates your local repo with the content from your remote repo.  Once you've done that, you can merge in the remotes master into your branch. `git merge origin/master`  where "origin" is the name of the remote repo, and "master" is the name of the branch that contains other peoples changes.